# ScriptIntrinsicBLAS equivalent for API 17

Tags: android, linear-algebra, renderscript, hardware-acceleration

[*ScriptIntrinsicBLAS*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.html) is supported in API 23 or superior. Is there any way to perform basic linear algebra operations in API 17 without having to write custom RS kernels?

The [RenderScript Runtime API Reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/overview.html) seems to provide operations like dot product and normalization, but it only supports vectors of 4 dimensions (e.g. double4), not limitless vectors represented as allocations (like ScriptIntrinsicBLAS does).

Any insights would be greatly appreciatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScriptIntrinsicBLAS is available in [RenderScript support lib](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBLAS.html).

You need to have the following in build.gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled true
    }
```

Recommended build environment:

```
Android Studio 2.2.3 or higher
Build-Tools 24.0.3 or higher
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 or higher
```